# CMake-based build of CUDA app fails - no files passed to linker

Tags: c++, build, cmake, cuda, linker

I'm trying to use CMake with a CUDA project of mine, but I'm having trouble getting it to build the executable when compiled on a system that has a CUDA-enabled device.

The `CMakeLists.txt` in question is below. It supports systems with and without CUDA-enabled devices, and builds just fine on my Macbook which doesn't have CUDA.

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
message(STATUS "CMake version: ${CMAKE_VERSION}")
project(stockModel)

# Grab the CUDA package
find_package(CUDA)
set(GPU_ACCELERATED ${CUDA_FOUND})

# Set directory and compilation flags for both g++ and nvcc
set(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -pthread")
set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS}
    -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50; -std=c++11; -lcurand;"
   )
set(CUDA_PROPAGATE_HOST_FLAGS off)

# Add directories
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/)
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/core/)
if (${GPU_ACCELERATED})
  include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/support/)
endif()

# Setup environments, depending on GPU accel. status
set(SRCS build/main.cpp core/callModels.cpp)
set(INCS core/callModels.h)

if (${GPU_ACCELERATED})
  set(SRCS ${SRCS} support/prng.cu support/debugCFP.cu)
  set(INCS ${INCS} support/prng.h support/debugCFP.h)

  set_source_files_properties(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/core/callModels.cpp
                          PROPERTIES CUDA_SOURCE_PROPERTY_FORMAT OBJ
                         )
  set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}
                          -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcuda -lcudart"
 )
endif()

# Create executable
message(STATUS "Sources: ${SRCS}")
message(STATUS "Includes: ${INCS}")
cuda_add_executable(stockModel ${SRCS} ${INCS})
```

The error I get when I attempt to build on my Jetson TX1 is as follows:

```
...
[ 80%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/stockModel.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable stockModel
c++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
...
```

Any ideas as to what is going wrong here? Obviously it has something to do with the CUDA 'extras', but I'm at a loss as to what is causing this.

Let me know if you need more details.

Here is the relevant part of the verbose output:

```
...
[100%] Linking CXX executable stockModel
/usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/stockModel.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++   -std=c++11 -pthread  
c++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

I've uploaded the full `make VERBOSE=1` output to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9b15bc8c6a2682206b29a42267060bdd) on GitHub.

Comment: cmake verbose output (showing the actual compile command line that triggered the error) might help.  The command line is obviously malformed if the compiler thinks there are no input files on it.  Seeing the actual command line may give some clues.

Comment: Looks like you were right, the linker simply isn't getting any input files. So I'm assuming something I've done has caused cuda_add_executable to not be set up properly?



`/usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/stockModel.dir        /link.txt --verbose=1
usr/bin/c++   -std=c++11 -pthread  
c++: fatal error: no input files`

Comment: Here is the full gist: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9b15bc8c6a2682206b29a42267060bdd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMake is sometimes finicky about spaces and list combinations. I know that doesn't sound like much of an explanation, but I'm not much of an expert.

What you need to do is replace this:

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}
                          -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcuda -lcudart"
```

with this:

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcuda -lcudart")
```

(single line). That should do it. At least - it does on my system (I created dummy source files with your files' names to try this out).

Comment: That was it, it seems putting everything on one line sorted it out. I suppose that is what I get for attempting to make it a bit easier on the eyes. Thanks!!

Comment: @DavidS.: You can split a single string into several lines with a backslashes, I think.